# Linking error for compiling Cython on aarch64

Tags: c, cython, arm64, cythonize

I am trying to make an executable on aarch64 using cython.

I know these flags are excessive, I tried compiling it on my x86_64 system and it worked with just `gcc -I/usr/include/python3.9 -lpython3.9 sample.c` but on aarch64 it gives these long linking errors.

If anyone has managed to make an executable on arm64 using cython that would also help.

```
root@f6753f1e6043:~# cython sample.pyx --embed -X language_level=3
```

```
root@f6753f1e6043:~# python3-config --ldflags --libs --cflags --embed
-L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-aarch64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -lm 
-lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm -lm 
-I/usr/include/python3.8 -I/usr/include/python3.8  -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.8-pqDzXG/python3.8-3.8.10=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector -Wformat -Werror=format-security  -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall
```

```
root@f6753f1e6043:~# gcc $(python3-config --ldflags --libs --cflags --embed) sample.c
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `__Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr':
/root/sample.c:1489: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttr'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `__Pyx_copy_spec_to_module':
/root/sample.c:1258: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1261: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `_Py_NoneStruct' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/root/sample.c:1261:(.text.unlikely+0xbc): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1261: undefined reference to `_Py_NoneStruct'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1262: undefined reference to `PyDict_SetItemString'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `_Py_DECREF':
/usr/include/python3.8/object.h:478: undefined reference to `_Py_Dealloc'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `__Pyx_copy_spec_to_module':
/root/sample.c:1265: undefined reference to `PyExc_AttributeError'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `PyExc_AttributeError' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/root/sample.c:1265:(.text.unlikely+0xfc): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1265: undefined reference to `PyExc_AttributeError'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1265: undefined reference to `PyErr_ExceptionMatches'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1266: undefined reference to `PyErr_Clear'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `__Pyx_check_single_interpreter':
/root/sample.c:1237: undefined reference to `PyThreadState_Get'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1237: undefined reference to `PyInterpreterState_GetID'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1250: undefined reference to `PyExc_ImportError'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `PyExc_ImportError' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/root/sample.c:1250:(.text.unlikely+0x17c): dangerous relocation: unsupported relocation
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1250: undefined reference to `PyExc_ImportError'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1250: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `__pyx_pymod_create':
/root/sample.c:1278: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
/usr/bin/ld: /root/sample.c:1280: undefined reference to `PyModule_NewObject'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `_Py_DECREF':
/usr/include/python3.8/object.h:478: undefined reference to `_Py_Dealloc'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `__pyx_pymod_create':
/root/sample.c:1283: undefined reference to `PyModule_GetDict'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: in function `_Py_DECREF':
/usr/include/python3.8/object.h:478: undefined reference to `_Py_Dealloc'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o: relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol `__stack_chk_guard@@GLIBC_2.17' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccBjCsrj.o(.text.unlikely+0x2e0): unresolvable R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 relocation against symbol `__stack_chk_guard@@GLIBC_2.17'
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `relocation R_AARCH64_ADR_PREL_PG_HI21 against symbol \`PyExc_AttributeError' which may bind externally can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC` Maybe this error is the root cause.

Comment: @kiner_shah tried it didn't work

Comment: What didn't work? What did you try? Any error messages?